# list is not being closed after finishing computation

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

For practice I wrote a Haskell program to find prime factors.

The code is the following:

```
getfactors :: Int -> [Int]
getfactors n = [x | x<-[1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

prime :: Int -> Bool
prime n | getfactors n == [1,n] = True
        | otherwise              = False

primefactors :: Int -> [Int]
primefactors n = [x | x <- getfactors n, prime x == True]
```

Everything works fine for small numbers, but when I enter large numbers the computation stops at the biggest prime factor and the expected list does not close. 
For example:

```
>primefactors 1263
[3,421]
>primefactors 1387781234
[2,7,2161,6553
```

An explanation is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think it is just a very slow algorithm that you are using. The computation does not appear to actually stop. If I compile this with `-O2` and try to print your second example from `main`, it (fully) completes in a few seconds. It is checking many more numbers after `6553` since `1387781234` is quite a bit bigger than `6553`. Since it is doing this fairly slowly and `6553` is the last prime factor, it gives the appearance of stopping on the last factor before it prints the final bracket (even though it is continuing and should stop if you allow it to finish).

Comment: `getfactors` can be improved to *O(sqrt(n))*, which will help a lot.  Hint: factors come in pairs.

Comment: This is not only slow, but I suspect it is wrong. `primefactors 4` computes `[2]`, I'd expect `[2,2]`.

Comment: @franky the code works as intended, as I just want to get the different prime factors uniquely.

Comment: the canonical trial division definition is [`primeFactors`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Testing_primality); seen in many answers here on SO as well. you can "uniquify" it with `map head . group`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could not reproduce:

```
> :set +s
> primefactors 1387781234
[2,7,2161,6553]
(368.04 secs, 288,660,869,072 bytes)
```

Your algorithm is just very slow. There are lots of ways to improve it:

- You are checking primality by trial division of all numbers smaller than the candidate. You can improve (without changing algorithm) by checking only up to the square root of the candidate.
- Besides trial division, there are a wide range of other primality checking algorithms running the full spectrum from "simple but slow" to "complicated as heck but blazing fast". Other Internet sources will have plenty of details.
- If you want to factor many numbers, it may be beneficial to memoize your primality checks between calls -- e.g. by storing a list of primes and iterating over them instead of iterating over all numbers. Since this is the only consumer of your primality check, you may want to consider creating this list directly rather than implementing a primality-checking algorithm first; again there's a wide range of algorithms for this running the spectrum from simple to fast.
- Once you find a factor, you can divide the number you are factoring by that to get a smaller, faster number to compute the remaining factors with.

There are probably other easy opportunities to speed things up, and lots of prior work to read about online. Enjoy!